# MySQL Query 2 tables unrelated column

Tags: mysql, join

I want to query 2 tables.

Here are the table structures :

**FAQ**

```
faq_id | member_id | answer
```

**workers**

```
id | faq_id | owner1 | owner2
```

what i try to do here is :

```
SELECT faqs.*, workbasket.* FROM faqs 
INNER JOIN workbasket 
WHERE faqs.member_id = 1
AND workbasekt.owner1 = 1 OR workbasekt.owner2 = 1
```

Comment: Use a comma-separated list of tables if you don't want to join them: `FROM faqs, workbasket`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT FAQ.*, workers.* FROM FAQ INNER JOIN workers on FAQ.faq_id = workers.faq_id
WHERE FAQ.member_id = 1 AND (workers.owner1 = 1 OR workers.owner2 = 1)
```

You need to be a bit more descriptive and explain what columns you want returned, what tables you want information from, and how those tables should be joined together.